# Signing a transaction: What is actually signed? [noob question]

Tags: transactions, signature, raw-transaction, ecdsa

I'm trying to wrap my head around how signing transactions actually works. As I understand ECDSA signatures roughly work like this: There is a magic function, let's call it `sign` that takes two parameters. The `private key` and the `message`. It outputs the signature or in the case of web3.py or web3.js, three weird values `v`, `r`, and `s`.

So when users sign a message they are basically signing a blob of data which is the `message` value in the `sign` function. Am I correct in this assumption?
So when users sign a message they are basically signing a blob of data which is the message value in the sign function. Am I correct in this assumption?

How can I access that data blob? Is it possible to get it from a public transaction via web3?

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f) and there it says that the data hash that will be signed is created from `rlp + hash`. Has anyone an idea what `rpl` means or how to get the output hash with web3?

Comment: Have you read this: [Mastering Ethereum - Transactions - Digital Signatures](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#digital-signatures)?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Thanks! This helped me solve [this issue here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78815/ethers-js-recover-public-key-from-contract-deployment-via-v-r-s-values/78897)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECDSA works with numbers so to sign a message first you have to encode it as an number.

The precise meaning of [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) is defined in the Yellow Paper (Appendix B Recursive Length Prefix). It is a function that will encode something structured (a transaction for example) as a sequence of bytes. Given a transaction `Transaction` then `RLP(Transaction)` returns a sequence of bytes.

Actually ECDSA numbers they also have to be in a range. To ensure the `RLP(Transaction)` is withing the correct ECDSA range we apply a hash function like `KECCAK256(RLP(Transaction))`.

Also the exact details of the ECDSA signature are in the Yellow Paper (Appending F Signing Transactions).

> r, s, v = ECDSASign(KECCAK256(RLP(Transaction)), PrivateKey)