# ethers.js Recover public key from contract deployment via v,r,s values

Tags: contract-deployment, public-key, ecrecover, ethers.js

I'm currently trying to get the public key of the user that deploys a contract. Unfortunately I can't make it work.

I am trying to achieve this solely by using ethers.js as I don't want to bloat my React build with other packages. I can easily get the public key from a given signature using the following code taken from [this issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/447).

```js
    let msg = "This is a normal string.";
    let sig = await signer.signMessage(msg);
    const msgHash = ethers.utils.hashMessage(msg);
    const msgHashBytes = ethers.utils.arrayify(msgHash);
    const recoveredPubKey = ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey(msgHashBytes, sig);
    const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.recoverAddress(msgHashBytes, sig);
```

When deploying a contract I should be able to do the same thing by simply stitching together the `r`, `s` and `v` values taken from the `deployTransaction`. The example [in the documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-utils.html#signatures) is similar. Here's my code:

```js
    const deployTx = contract.deployTransaction;
    const msgHash = ethers.utils.hashMessage(deployTx.raw);
    const dataBytes = ethers.utils.arrayify(msgHash);
    const expanded = {
      r: deployTx.r,
      s: deployTx.s,
      recoveryParam: 0,
      v: deployTx.v
    };
    const signature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(expanded);

    // now the signature should be correctly formatted
    const recoveredPubKey = ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey(dataBytes, signature);
    const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.recoverAddress(dataBytes, signature);
```

This approach does not work. As far as I know the data that was signed during the deployment is in `deployTransaction.raw`. So this **should** work. But I tested it with `deployTransaction.data` as well.

To me it looks like the signature might be wrong. The `joinSignature` automatically converts the `v` value to either 27 or 28. According to [EIP155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) this doesn't make any sense?

**Edit:** To clarify, I think all I need is the true signing hash. How can I generate it? It's apparently not the hash of the raw deployment transaction.

**Edit 2:** After some research in the ethereum book I found this:

```
In Ethereum’s implementation of ECDSA, the "message" being signed is the transaction, or more accurately, the Keccak-256 hash of the RLP-encoded data from the transaction. The signing key is the EOA’s private key.
```

So I changed my code to the following:

```js
    const deployTx = contract.deployTransaction;
    const msg = ethers.utils.RLP.encode(deployTx.data);
    const msgHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(msg);
    const msgBytes = ethers.utils.arrayify(msgHash);
    const expanded = {
      r: deployTx.r,
      s: deployTx.s,
      recoveryParam: 0,
      v: deployTx.v
    };
    const signature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(expanded);
    const recoveredPubKey = ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey(
      msgBytes,
      signature
    );
    const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.recoverAddress(msgBytes, signature);
```

This still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Depending if EIP155 applies or not, you have to remove r, s, v from the for the message to be signed or replace them by zeros. Look a this typescript implementation https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/v2.1.2/src/transaction.ts#L182-L192 (to sign it is called `tx.hash(false)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solved now. There was a tiny bug in the code and in the `ethers` library that would not correctly return the chainId and calculate the `v` value. It's fixed now, see [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/700). Many thanks to ricmoo for helping out.

I wrote a [gist that correctly recovers the public key given the transaction](https://gist.github.com/chrsengel/2b29809b8f7281b8f10bbe041c1b5e00).

In short:

```js
const tx = await provider.getTransaction(...)
const expandedSig = {
  r: tx.r,
  s: tx.s,
  v: tx.v
}
const signature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(expandedSig)
const txData = {
  gasPrice: tx.gasPrice,
  gasLimit: tx.gasLimit,
  value: tx.value,
  nonce: tx.nonce,
  data: tx.data,
  chainId: tx.chainId,
  to: tx.to // you might need to include this if it's a regular tx and not simply a contract deployment
}
const rsTx = await ethers.utils.resolveProperties(txData)
const raw = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(rsTx) // returns RLP encoded tx
const msgHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(raw) // as specified by ECDSA
const msgBytes = ethers.utils.arrayify(msgHash) // create binary hash
const recoveredPubKey = ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey(msgBytes, signature)
const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.recoverAddress(msgBytes, signature)
```

Comment: This is really great. For some reason, it is not working for me tho. The address generated is not correct. I am trying to do this with the transaction on mumbai-polygon ```0xa0933a136d9d1166defc5f841089055a9f94208704b0fcbed618713aa3d6a4bd``` which was made by the address ```0xdb326d217c2452faebb40aceb75000f0bb986703```, but the algorithm gets ```

Comment: ```0xD4969Eb27CE47013058Ed27ac2210C4dce5CE111```

Answer (score 2):

I've updated answer by Chris and put it into a function.
Confirmed to be working correctly in my code.

```typescript
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export async function recover(tx: ethers.Transaction): Promise<{
  publicKey: string;
  address: string;
}> {
  const expandedSig = {
    r: tx.r!,
    s: tx.s!,
    v: tx.v!,
  };

  const signature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(expandedSig);

  const txData = {
    gasLimit: tx.gasLimit,
    value: tx.value,
    nonce: tx.nonce,
    data: tx.data,
    chainId: tx.chainId,
    to: tx.to, // you might need to include this if it's a regular tx and not simply a contract deployment
    type: tx.type,
    maxFeePerGas: tx.maxFeePerGas,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: tx.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
  };

  const rsTx = await ethers.utils.resolveProperties(txData);
  const raw = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(rsTx); // returns RLP encoded tx
  const msgHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(raw); // as specified by ECDSA
  const msgBytes = ethers.utils.arrayify(msgHash); // create binary hash

  return {
    publicKey: ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey(msgBytes, signature),
    address: ethers.utils.recoverAddress(msgBytes, signature),
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I executed the above code and it gave me a hash starting with 0x for the public key, but the public key I get is 132 characters. Am I doing something wrong? because I read that Ethereum public keys are 64 characters.